# Adding Alert for Expiration Date of Membership or ID Card

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning, it's the first time on Stack Overflow and I hope to ask the question in a proper way.

Here's my problem:

I want to add an expire user notification for two events: Annual Membership and ID Card.

Expire User Alert for Annual Membership: my idea is to use Expire Users plugin and set automatically the expire date from Order Completed status in Woocommerce to 365 days.

Expire User Alert for ID Card: my idea is to set an alert based on expiration date of the id card. This data is already set during the checkout phase by the customer.

The problem I have is all due to how to code this, my php is very very basic, if you can help me by code I'll build a Golden Statue, if you have some solution or articles related to read I'll build a Silver Statue :D

Waiting for your kind reply, thanks in advance

21/07/2021 15:23

```
// update user data with order completed date, I use shipping_address_1 to store it, I'm not using the original address in my site

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_save_user_meta' );

function checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $orderday = $order->get_date_completed;

   $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
   if ( $order->get_date_completed() ) {  
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $orderday );
   }
} 

//take the updated data to set an alert via mail in 365 days
 if (!function_exists('expirationalert')) {

            function expirationalert($user_id) {
                $blogusers = get_users('role=client');
                // Array of WP_User objects.
                foreach ($blogusers as $user) {

                    //$user->user_registered;
                    // $user_id=$user->ID;
                    $user->user_registered;

                    $user_id = $user->ID;

                    $user_login = $user->user_login;

                    $user_email = $user->user_email;

                    $startingdate = $user->shipping_address_1;

                    /* input expire date format -> Y-m-d */
                    list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $startingdate);
                    $nowdate = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
                    $expirationdate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, date("Y"));

                    if ($expirationdate < $nowdate)
                        $expirationdate = $expirationdate + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);

                    $daycount = intval(($expirationdate - $nowdate) / (60 * 60 * 24));

                    //echo $daycount; 

                    if ($daycount < 349) {

                        /* echo $user->user_registered;
                          echo "<br/>";
                          echo $user_id=$user->ID;
                          echo "<br/>";
                          echo $user_login=$user->user_login;
                          echo "<br/>";
                          echo $user_email=$user->user_email;
                          echo "<br/>"; */

                        $message = sprintf(__('your Account will be expired in next 15 days %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
                        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
                        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";

                        @wp_mail(
                                        $user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Account Expiration alert'), get_option('blogname')), $message
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
```

The second part is inspired from this thread [I want to create a wordpress user registration function so that both user and admin should get email alert after every year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079598/i-want-to-create-a-wordpress-user-registration-function-so-that-both-user-and-ad)

I'm 100% it's not the right code or pretending it'll work, I think it can be the starting point to polish it and make it work.
The code is only for the product part, I presume if I can make it work, for the second code I have just to refer to my custom field with the ID Card Expiration Date.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code. Without knowing what you have started, we can't help you with where to go

Comment: Hi Jacob, I pasted the "wannabe" code up here